# How to filter out TCP retransmission packets using tcpdump

Tags: tcp, wireshark, packet, tcpdump

I have a pcap file which I am analyzing. Basically in this file there are some TCP Retransmission packets which I want to filter out and leave the others. I know how to do it in wireshark using:

```
not tcp.analysis.fast_retransmission and not tcp.analysis.retransmission
```

But how can i do it using tcpdump?

My pcap file looks like this:
[image]

I have tried using `tcp[tcpflags] & tcp-syn != 0 and tcp[tcpflags] & tcp-ack != 0` but still not sucessful